# How do I "decompile" Java class files?

Tags: java, decompiler

What program can I use to decompile a class file? Will I actually get Java code, or is it just JVM assembly code?

On Java performance questions on this site I often see responses from people who have "decompiled" the Java class file to see how the compiler optimizes certain things.

Comment: The art of "decompiling" can also be thought upon as reverse engineering. Although sometimes when reverse engineering something you don't always have access to binaries.

Comment: No one mentioned https://bytecodeviewer.com/, which can decompile to java source and to bytecode (for java source is based on JAD).

Answer (score 588, accepted):

Update February 2016:

[www.javadecompilers.com](http://www.javadecompilers.com/) lists JAD as being:

> the most popular Java decompiler, but primarily of this age only. Written in C++, so very fast.
>   Outdated, unsupported and does not decompile correctly Java 5 and later

So your mileage may vary with recent jdk (7, 8).

The same site list other tools.

And javadecompiler, as noted by [Salvador Valencia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1377112/salvador-valencia) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files/272595#comment79458645_272595) (Sept 2017), offers a SaaS where you upload the `.class` file to the cloud and it returns you the decompiled code.

---

Original answer: Oct. 2008

- The final release of JSR 176, defining the major features of J2SE 5.0 (Java SE 5), has been published on September 30, 2004.
- The lastest Java version supported by JAD, the famous Java decompiler written by Mr. Pavel Kouznetsov, is **[JDK 1.3](http://varaneckas.com/jad/)**.
- Most of the Java decompilers downloadable today from the Internet, such as “DJ Java Decompiler” or “Cavaj Java Decompiler”, are powered by JAD: they can not display Java 5 sources.

[Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) (Yet another Fast Java decompiler) has:

- Explicit support for decompiling and analyzing **Java 5+** “.class” files.
- A nice GUI:

[image: screenshot]

It works with compilers from JDK 1.1.8 up to JDK 1.7.0, and others ([Jikes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jikes), [JRockit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRockit), etc.).

It features an online [live demo version](http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-online) that is actually fully functional! You can just drop a jar file on the page and see the decompiled source code without installing anything.

Comment: +1 It's worth mentioning that it's also modularized, so the core (implemented in C++) can be leveraged elsewhere.

Comment: jd-gui-0.3.3 also available [here](http://code.google.com/p/innlab/downloads/detail?name=jd-gui-0.3.3.windows.zip&can=2&q=)

Comment: +1 for the info! If Java decompilers are so damn easy, how does one go about protecting his IP? Is there an obfuscation technique to work around these decompilers?

Comment: @Rishi I suppose there is, when I look at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+obfuscation

Comment: In case one installed the Eclipse java decompiler plugin on Eclipse Juno, and Eclipse started hanging on Marketplace DND Initialization forcing to kill the whole process: removing the jd.*.jar from Eclipse plugins directory just fixed it for me.

Comment: If you don't like using the jd-gui, you can follow these instructions and generate the folder hierarchy for the code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1384652/198348

Comment: @Rishi the same way you protect your IP in any language or platform - good lawyers. DRM is only a bandaid.

Comment: There are only some small shortages (e.g. some types are not recovered), but overall is this an excellent tool, VonC

Comment: JD-GUI project is outdated and long dead.

Comment: It now offers SaaS where you upload the .class file to the cloud and it returns you the decompiled code. Worked for a simple POJO.

Comment: @SalvadorValencia Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @Salvador Valencia Please add sources.

Answer (score 101):

There are a few decompilers out there... A quick search yields:

1. [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon): open-source (Apache 2) and actively developed
2. [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau): open-source (GPLv3) and actively developed
3. [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/): open-source (MIT) and actively developed
4. [JAD](http://varaneckas.com/jad/)
5. [DJ Java Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/)
6. [Mocha](http://www.brouhaha.com/~eric/software/mocha/)

And many more.

These produce Java code. Java comes with something that lets you see JVM byte code ([javap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html)).

Comment: May I also add, that Procyon, CFR, JAD and DJ are available as a web-service: http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Comment: http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html is some AD link

Comment: Thanks @marcinj,  I found another link that has links to download it.

Answer (score 51):

To see Java source code check some decompiler. Go search for **jad**.

If you want to see bytecodes, just use **javap** which comes with the JDK.

Comment: I'd recommend one of the open-source decompilers instead, as they are actively developed. Use [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler), the [CFR decompiler](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/) or [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) (Python) instead.

Answer (score 29):

I tried several, and [Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler) seemed to work the best for me. It's under active development and supports many features of the latest versions of Java.

These are the others I tried:

- [CFR](http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/)

  - Promising, but often failed method decompilation. I'll be keeping my eye on this one. Also actively developed with support for the latest Java features.
- [Krakatau](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau)

  - Takes a different approach in that it tries to output equivalent Java code instead of trying to reconstruct the original source, which has the potential of making it better for obfuscated code. From my testing it was roughly on par with Procyon, but still nice to have something different. I did have to use the `-skip` command-line flag so it wouldn't stop on errors. Actively developed, and interestingly enough it's written in Python.
- [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/)

  - Worked, but Procyon's output was much better. Here's a [page comparing Procyon output to the original and JD-GUI](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Decompiler%20Output%20Comparison). JD-GUI is also available as an [Eclipse plugin](http://jd.benow.ca/#jd-eclipse), which didn't work for me at all. Doesn't seem to be open source and development seems sporadic.
- [JAD](http://varaneckas.com/jad/)

  - Worked, but only supports Java 1.4 and below. Also available as an [Eclipse plugin](http://jadclipse.sourceforge.net/). No longer under development.

Comment: Note that the `IGNORE_EXCEPTIONS` thing has now been changed to the command line flag `-skip`.

Answer (score 18):

I use [JAD Decompiler](http://www.javadecompilers.com/jad).

There is an [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) plugin for it, [jadeclipse](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/). It is pretty nice.

Answer (score 14):

**[Procyon](https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon)** includes a decompiler. It is FOSS.

Answer (score 13):

[**Soot**](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/soot/) is an option for newer Java code. At least it has the advantage of still being recently maintained...

Also, [**Java Decompiler**](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) is a decompiler with both a stand-alone GUI and Eclipse integration.

Lastly, [**Jdec**](http://jdec.sourceforge.net/) hasn't been mentioned, though it's not as polished as other options.

Comment: Do you know how to decompile a concrete class file with Soot? I'm not sure it's possible...

Answer (score 12):

[JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) is really good. You could just open a [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file and browse through the code as if
you are working on an IDE. Good stuff.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a list of decompilers as of Feb 2015:

**Procyon**, open-source, https://bitbucket.org/mstrobel/procyon/wiki/Java%20Decompiler

**CFR**, free, no source-code available,  http://www.benf.org/other/cfr/

**JD**, free for non-commercial use only, http://jd.benow.ca/

**Fernflower**, open-source, https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower,

**JAD** – given here only for historical reason. Free, no source-code available, http://varaneckas.com/jad/
Outdated, unsupported and does not decompile correctly Java 5 and later.

You may test above-mentioned decompilers online, no installation required and make your own educated choice.

**Java decompilers in the cloud:**  http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Answer (score 10):

There are a few programs you can use. You will get the actual Java code, but sometimes the code will have been obfuscated so methods are named by one letter or number or a random mix of letters and numbers.

[DJ Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/)
[Mocha](http://www.brouhaha.com/~eric/software/mocha/)

Answer (score 9):

Most decompilers for Java are based on [JAD](http://www.kpdus.com/jad.html).  It's a great tool, but unfortunately hasn't been updated for a while and does not handle Java 1.5+ classes very well.  I have not seen any tools that will properly handle 1.5+ classes.

Comment: here you go: I just posted an answer to your answer ;) JDK1.5 and more supported!

Comment: "I have not seen any tools that will properly handle 1.5+ classes" - Procion,Fernflower,JDCore and CFR (this one handles Java 8!)

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at [cavaj](http://www.bysoft.se/sureshot/cavaj/).

Comment: That also uses `jad` underneath.

Answer (score 6):

All of the JAD links listed so far far seem to be broken, so I found this site. Works great (for Linux, at least)! On Ubuntu 11.10 I had to download the static one for whatever reason.

http://www.varaneckas.com/jad

Answer (score 5):

- JAD is one that works and is simple.
- Also, if you just want to see the methods, use javap.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see how the Java compiler does certain things, you don't want decompilation, you want disassembly. Decompilation involves transforming the bytecode into Java source, meaning that a lot of low level information is lost, and if you're wondering about compiler optimization, this is probably the very information you're interested in.

Anyway, I happen to have written an [open source Java disassembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau). Unlike Javap, this works even on highly pathological classes, so you can see what obfuscation tools are doing to your classes as well. It can also do decompilation, though I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

JAD doesn't work for me (Ubuntu 11.10 issue) so I've moved forward and sopped on [JODO](http://jode.sourceforge.net/). At least it has Open Java source code and been able to decompile my *.class* properly.

I recommend to check out *'branches/generic'* branch first. The trunks is not stable.

Comment: JODO is [sporadically maintained](http://sourceforge.net/p/jode/code/1418/tree/trunk/jode/) while CFR and Procyon are actively developed and have JDK 8 support.

Answer (score 4):

On IntelliJ IDEA platform you can use [Java Decompiler IntelliJ Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7100). It allows you to display all the Java sources during your debugging process, even if you do not have them all. It is based on the famous tools [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/).

[image]

Comment: @NoOP's Are you a robot? Or just not paying attention to a subject of review?

Comment: Sorry for that, at first glance it seems like link only answer. Maybe you should add more details and also your answer only comply with question title not with content of question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Chris have you tried the suggested solution? Have you even **read the question**?

Comment: @NoOP's sorry for being rude =( I am overwhelmed by the number of reviewers who don't pay attention.

Answer (score 1):

For OSX I recommend: jarzilla or JD-GUI

They both allow you to view jar,war,etc. file content and decompiles any class files inside of them.

Jarzilla: https://code.google.com/p/jarzilla/
JD-GUI: http://jd.benow.ca/

Answer (score 1):

With [AndroChef Java Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/ac_decompiler.html) you can decompile apk, dex, jar and java class-files. It's simple and easy. AndroChef JD is based on [FernFlower](https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower). You can evaluate it in 10 free uses.

> AndroChef supports Java language features like generics, enums and annotations. According to some studies, AndroChef Java Decompiler is able to decompile 98.04% of Java applications generated with traditional Java compilers - a very high recovery rate. It is simple but powerful tool that allows you to decompile Java and Dalvik bytecode (DEX, APK) into readable Java source.

Comment: @Dimitrius, please read answers carefully during a review. How do you imagine including a FernFlower or AndroChef here?