# Re-Implement 3rd party TCP Java client

Tags: c#, java, .net, networking, reverse-engineering

I need to know if there are any tools to figure out the interface to a TCP client.  My Company has purchased a 3rd party tool and we really like the Server side and most of the client side.

I would like to see if I can figure out the calls that the client side makes to the server so I can create the client side functionality we want.

I have been able to figure out what the port number and protocol that the client communicates with the server on.  Since we host the server, I have full access to that too.

Any ideas on how to get hold of and execute the methods that the client app is calling on the server?

I am not that good at java, so I would like to use C#.NET if at all possible.  Does that sound feasible?

NOTE: I have done something like this before (connect to a 3rd party Java Based Server with a custom .NET client) but that time I had a bit of documentation to get me started. This time I have nothing.

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Also, if you know better tags for this please post them as comments (or just re-tag if you have the permissions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're trying to reverse engineer the protocol so you can write your own client to the server, get [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).  You can use it to follow the conversation between client and server.

Comment: If the client runs on Unix, truss/trace/strace/dtrace (depending on the Unix dialect) to see the system/library calls the program makes may also be useful.

Comment: Too bad there is not something like that for windows. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to [decompile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files) the library.  That should give you all of the low-level info that you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [TCPMon](https://tcpmon.dev.java.net/) to grab the exact message text passed between client and server.