# Do my producer for ActiveMQ uses FailoverTransport?

Tags: activemq-classic, failover, producer

I have a producer for ActiveMQ. It was made by a company for us. We just have the executable, not the source code.
For September, we will have an ActiveMQ cluster with a virtual IP and we need to use failover transport on all our consumers and producers.
So i contact the company who made the producer to ask if they already coded the producer with failover transport and they propose me a solution to implement it.
BUT, when i look at the log made by the producer, i can see this :

```
<log4j:event logger="org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport" timestamp="1535103598670" level="DEBUG" thread="ActiveMQ Task-1">
<log4j:message><![CDATA[Connection established]]></log4j:message>
</log4j:event>
```

As you can see, it mentions the Class FailoverTransport which normally is used for failover right? That's why i'm wondering that the failover is already included in our producer and i suspect that the company don't tell us and want to make money on our back to implement the failover which is already implemented in our producer in fact.

What do you think about this? Why do they use that class if it is not for the failover? Is there a way to know that without the source code?

Thanks in advance for your future answers.

Comment: I was right. The company have proposed a solution  to implement the failover but it was already implemented in the app. He tells me in a second mail when i have insisted that what i have seen in the log shows that the connection is made with the failover.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to tell specifically how/why a class is used without the source code.  FWIW, you could probably derive the source-code yourself using a Java decompiler.  See [Convert .class to .java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225537/convert-class-to-java) for more details.