# How to fix decompile .class to .java error

Tags: java, bytecode, converters

I try to convert a `.class` file to `.java` file, but after converting, I noticed that some of the code was not converted, and with comment `/*Error*/` they were written *bytecode*. As:

```
/* Error */
private LineData getDataSetPrHour(LinkedHashMap<String, Float> paramLinkedHashMap, String paramString) {
    // Byte code:
    //   0: new 340 java/util/ArrayList
    //   3: dup
    //   4: invokespecial 341   java/util/ArrayList:<init>  ()V
    //   7: astore_3
    //   8: aload_0
    //   9: new 340 java/util/ArrayList
    //   12: dup
    //   13: invokespecial 341  java/util/ArrayList:<init>  ()V
    //   16: putfield 323   no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:labels Ljava/util/ArrayList;
    //   19: aload_1
    //   20: invokevirtual 347  java/util/LinkedHashMap:size    ()I
    //   23: iconst_1
    //   24: isub
    //   25: istore 4
    //   27: aload_1
    //   28: invokevirtual 351  java/util/LinkedHashMap:entrySet    ()Ljava/util/Set;
    //   31: invokeinterface 357 1 0
    //   36: astore 5
    //   38: iconst_0
    //   39: istore 6
    //   41: aload 5
    //   43: invokeinterface 363 1 0
    //   48: istore 7
    //   50: aconst_null
    //   51: astore 8
    //   53: iload 7
    //   55: ifeq +426 -> 481
    //   58: aload 5
    //   60: invokeinterface 367 1 0
    //   65: checkcast 369  java/util/Map$Entry
    //   68: astore 10
    //   70: aload 10
    //   72: invokeinterface 372 1 0
    //   77: checkcast 131  java/lang/String
    //   80: astore 11
    //   82: aload_3
    //   83: new 374    com/github/mikephil/charting/data/Entry
    //   86: dup
    //   87: aload 10
    //   89: invokeinterface 377 1 0
    //   94: checkcast 379  java/lang/Float
    //   97: invokevirtual 383  java/lang/Float:floatValue  ()F
    //   100: iload 6
    //   102: invokespecial 386 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/Entry:<init>  (FI)V
    //   105: invokevirtual 389 java/util/ArrayList:add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    //   108: pop
    //   109: aload_2
    //   110: ldc_w 391
    //   113: invokevirtual 276 java/lang/String:equals (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    //   116: ifne +223 -> 339
    //   119: aload_2
    //   120: ldc_w 393
    //   123: invokevirtual 276 java/lang/String:equals (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    //   126: ifeq +6 -> 132
    //   129: goto +210 -> 339
    //   132: aload_2
    //   133: ldc_w 395
    //   136: invokevirtual 276 java/lang/String:equals (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    //   139: ifne +53 -> 192
    //   142: aload_2
    //   143: ldc_w 397
    //   146: invokevirtual 276 java/lang/String:equals (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    //   149: ifne +43 -> 192
    //   152: aload_2
    //   153: ldc_w 399
    //   156: invokevirtual 276 java/lang/String:equals (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    //   159: ifne +33 -> 192
    //   162: aload_2
    //   163: ldc_w 401
    //   166: invokevirtual 276 java/lang/String:equals (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    //   169: ifeq +6 -> 175
    //   172: goto +20 -> 192
    //   175: aload_2
    //   176: ldc_w 403
    //   179: invokevirtual 276 java/lang/String:equals (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    //   182: ifeq +264 -> 446
    //   185: aload 11
    //   187: astore 8
    //   189: goto +257 -> 446
    //   192: new 405   java/text/SimpleDateFormat
    //   195: dup
    //   196: ldc_w 407
    //   199: invokespecial 409 java/text/SimpleDateFormat:<init>   (Ljava/lang/String;)V
    //   202: astore 18
    //   204: aload 18
    //   206: aload 11
    //   208: invokevirtual 413 java/text/SimpleDateFormat:parse    (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Date;
    //   211: astore 19
    //   213: goto +7 -> 220
    //   216: aload 8
    //   218: astore 19
    //   220: aload_0
    //   221: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   224: invokestatic 419  android/text/format/DateFormat:getDateFormat    (Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/text/DateFormat;
    //   227: astore 20
    //   229: iload 6
    //   231: ifne +48 -> 279
    //   234: new 421   java/lang/StringBuilder
    //   237: dup
    //   238: invokespecial 422 java/lang/StringBuilder:<init>  ()V
    //   241: astore 21
    //   243: aload 21
    //   245: ldc_w 424
    //   248: invokevirtual 428 java/lang/StringBuilder:append  (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    //   251: pop
    //   252: aload 21
    //   254: aload 20
    //   256: aload 19
    //   258: invokevirtual 434 java/text/DateFormat:format (Ljava/util/Date;)Ljava/lang/String;
    //   261: invokevirtual 428 java/lang/StringBuilder:append  (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    //   264: pop
    //   265: aload 21
    //   267: invokevirtual 438 java/lang/StringBuilder:toString    ()Ljava/lang/String;
    //   270: astore 24
    //   272: aload 24
    //   274: astore 8
    //   276: goto +170 -> 446
    //   279: iload 6
    //   281: iload 4
    //   283: if_icmpne +44 -> 327
    //   286: new 421   java/lang/StringBuilder
    //   289: dup
    //   290: invokespecial 422 java/lang/StringBuilder:<init>  ()V
    //   293: astore 25
    //   295: aload 25
    //   297: aload 20
    //   299: aload 19
    //   301: invokevirtual 434 java/text/DateFormat:format (Ljava/util/Date;)Ljava/lang/String;
    //   304: invokevirtual 428 java/lang/StringBuilder:append  (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    //   307: pop
    //   308: aload 25
    //   310: ldc_w 440
    //   313: invokevirtual 428 java/lang/StringBuilder:append  (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    //   316: pop
    //   317: aload 25
    //   319: invokevirtual 438 java/lang/StringBuilder:toString    ()Ljava/lang/String;
    //   322: astore 24
    //   324: goto -52 -> 272
    //   327: aload 20
    //   329: aload 19
    //   331: invokevirtual 434 java/text/DateFormat:format (Ljava/util/Date;)Ljava/lang/String;
    //   334: astore 24
    //   336: goto -64 -> 272
    //   339: iload 6
    //   341: ifne +26 -> 367
    //   344: aload_0
    //   345: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   348: aload 11
    //   350: ldc_w 442
    //   353: ldc_w 444
    //   356: ldc_w 446
    //   359: invokestatic 452  no/fault/oilwidget/com/util:formatUTCDateStrToHourStr   (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    //   362: astore 8
    //   364: goto +82 -> 446
    //   367: iload 6
    //   369: iload 4
    //   371: if_icmpne +55 -> 426
    //   374: new 421   java/lang/StringBuilder
    //   377: dup
    //   378: invokespecial 422 java/lang/StringBuilder:<init>  ()V
    //   381: astore 13
    //   383: aload 13
    //   385: aload_0
    //   386: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   389: aload 11
    //   391: ldc_w 442
    //   394: ldc_w 444
    //   397: ldc_w 446
    //   400: invokestatic 452  no/fault/oilwidget/com/util:formatUTCDateStrToHourStr   (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    //   403: invokevirtual 428 java/lang/StringBuilder:append  (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    //   406: pop
    //   407: aload 13
    //   409: ldc_w 454
    //   412: invokevirtual 428 java/lang/StringBuilder:append  (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    //   415: pop
    //   416: aload 13
    //   418: invokevirtual 438 java/lang/StringBuilder:toString    ()Ljava/lang/String;
    //   421: astore 8
    //   423: goto +23 -> 446
    //   426: aload_0
    //   427: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   430: aload 11
    //   432: ldc_w 442
    //   435: ldc_w 444
    //   438: ldc_w 446
    //   441: invokestatic 452  no/fault/oilwidget/com/util:formatUTCDateStrToHourStr   (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    //   444: astore 8
    //   446: aload 8
    //   448: ifnull +16 -> 464
    //   451: aload_0
    //   452: getfield 323  no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:labels Ljava/util/ArrayList;
    //   455: aload 8
    //   457: invokevirtual 389 java/util/ArrayList:add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    //   460: pop
    //   461: goto +14 -> 475
    //   464: aload_0
    //   465: getfield 323  no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:labels Ljava/util/ArrayList;
    //   468: ldc_w 456
    //   471: invokevirtual 389 java/util/ArrayList:add (Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
    //   474: pop
    //   475: iinc 6 1
    //   478: goto -437 -> 41
    //   481: new 458   com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet
    //   484: dup
    //   485: aload_3
    //   486: aload 8
    //   488: invokespecial 461 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:<init>    (Ljava/util/List;Ljava/lang/String;)V
    //   491: astore 9
    //   493: aload 9
    //   495: iconst_1
    //   496: invokevirtual 464 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setDrawCubic  (Z)V
    //   499: aload 9
    //   501: aload_0
    //   502: getfield 72   no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:filled Z
    //   505: invokevirtual 467 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setDrawFilled (Z)V
    //   508: aload_0
    //   509: getfield 70   no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:dark_mode  Z
    //   512: ifeq +74 -> 586
    //   515: aload 9
    //   517: aload_0
    //   518: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   521: ldc_w 468
    //   524: invokestatic 210  android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat:getColor   (Landroid/content/Context;I)I
    //   527: invokevirtual 471 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setValueTextColor (I)V
    //   530: aload 9
    //   532: aload_0
    //   533: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   536: ldc_w 472
    //   539: invokestatic 210  android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat:getColor   (Landroid/content/Context;I)I
    //   542: invokevirtual 475 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setFillColor  (I)V
    //   545: aload 9
    //   547: aload_0
    //   548: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   551: ldc_w 476
    //   554: invokestatic 210  android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat:getColor   (Landroid/content/Context;I)I
    //   557: invokevirtual 479 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setColor  (I)V
    //   560: aload 9
    //   562: aload_0
    //   563: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   566: ldc_w 480
    //   569: invokestatic 210  android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat:getColor   (Landroid/content/Context;I)I
    //   572: invokevirtual 483 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setCircleColor    (I)V
    //   575: aload 9
    //   577: sipush 255
    //   580: invokevirtual 486 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setFillAlpha  (I)V
    //   583: goto +63 -> 646
    //   586: aload 9
    //   588: aload_0
    //   589: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   592: ldc_w 487
    //   595: invokestatic 210  android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat:getColor   (Landroid/content/Context;I)I
    //   598: invokevirtual 471 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setValueTextColor (I)V
    //   601: aload 9
    //   603: aload_0
    //   604: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   607: ldc_w 488
    //   610: invokestatic 210  android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat:getColor   (Landroid/content/Context;I)I
    //   613: invokevirtual 475 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setFillColor  (I)V
    //   616: aload 9
    //   618: aload_0
    //   619: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   622: ldc_w 489
    //   625: invokestatic 210  android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat:getColor   (Landroid/content/Context;I)I
    //   628: invokevirtual 479 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setColor  (I)V
    //   631: aload 9
    //   633: aload_0
    //   634: invokevirtual 152 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:getActivity    ()Landroid/app/Activity;
    //   637: ldc_w 490
    //   640: invokestatic 210  android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat:getColor   (Landroid/content/Context;I)I
    //   643: invokevirtual 483 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setCircleColor    (I)V
    //   646: aload 9
    //   648: ldc_w 491
    //   651: invokevirtual 494 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setCircleSize (F)V
    //   654: aload 9
    //   656: ldc -25
    //   658: invokevirtual 497 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setValueTextSize  (F)V
    //   661: aload 9
    //   663: iconst_0
    //   664: invokevirtual 500 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator   (Z)V
    //   667: aload 9
    //   669: iconst_0
    //   670: invokevirtual 503 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setDrawVerticalHighlightIndicator (Z)V
    //   673: aload 9
    //   675: new 12    no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment$4
    //   678: dup
    //   679: aload_0
    //   680: invokespecial 505 no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment$4:<init>   (Lno/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment;)V
    //   683: invokevirtual 509 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet:setValueFormatter (Lcom/github/mikephil/charting/formatter/ValueFormatter;)V
    //   686: new 511   com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineData
    //   689: dup
    //   690: aload_0
    //   691: getfield 323  no/fault/oilwidget/ChartFragment:labels Ljava/util/ArrayList;
    //   694: aload 9
    //   696: invokespecial 514 com/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineData:<init>   (Ljava/util/List;Lcom/github/mikephil/charting/data/LineDataSet;)V
    //   699: areturn
    // Local variable table:
    //   start  length  slot    name    signature
    //   0  700 0   this    ChartFragment
    //   0  700 1   paramLinkedHashMap  LinkedHashMap<String, Float>
    //   0  700 2   paramString String
    //   7  479 3   localArrayList  ArrayList
    //   25 347 4   i   int
    //   36 23  5   localIterator   java.util.Iterator
    //   39 437 6   j   int
    //   48 6   7   bool    boolean
    //   51 436 8   localObject1    Object
    //   491    204 9   localLineDataSet    com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet
    //   68 20  10  localEntry  java.util.Map.Entry
    //   80 351 11  str1    String
    //   381    36  13  localStringBuilder1 StringBuilder
    //   202    3   18  localSimpleDateFormat   java.text.SimpleDateFormat
    //   211    119 19  localObject2    Object
    //   216    1   19  localParseException java.text.ParseException
    //   227    101 20  localDateFormat java.text.DateFormat
    //   241    25  21  localStringBuilder2 StringBuilder
    //   270    65  24  str2    String
    //   293    25  25  localStringBuilder3 StringBuilder
    // Exception table:
    //   from   to  target  type
    //   204    213 216 java/text/ParseException
    return null;
}
```

How can I translate these code into Java?

Where to translate codes online / offline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert .class to .java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225537/convert-class-to-java)

Comment: @Talha - I don't see how that relates at all.

Comment: What decompiler are you using? What does its documentation say about what causes it to give up and just emit commented-out bytecode?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files

Comment: @Talha It's not work for me...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I use the [JD-GUI](http://java-decompiler.github.io/)

Comment: Are you trying to decompile a single java `.class` file? What is the java class version for the file[s] you are trying to decompile?

Answer (score 1):

All that means is that the decompiler you are using failed to decompile the method in question. You can try using different decompilers. Some decompilers are better than others and each has strengths and weaknesses. In particular, the [Krakatau decompiler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau) should easily be able to handle the code you posted, though it is a little hard to set up, especially when decompiling android code. Krakatau can handle nearly anything which isn't using `invokedynamic`. It can even decompile obfuscated code, though the results aren't as pretty as with traditional decompilers.

Comment: I try to use **Krakatau**. But It's could not translate the parts of the code that I wanted

Comment: Could you please post the jar? I can see if I can get it to work. Also post which methods or classes you are having issues with.

Comment: You can download jar file from [THIS LINK](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2j4hkga7z04n2c3/OilLive.jar?dl=0)

Comment: For example look at the `EnergyFragment.class`

Comment: I tried it and I was able to decompile EnergyFragment without errors. (You can see the result at https://pastebin.com/pqmtXjiv). Perhaps you forgot to include the right dependencies? For Krakatau, you need to have access to any libraries which the app depends on in order to decompile it properly.