# Reading *.WAR files

Tags: java, servlets, jar, war, executable-jar

I'm working on a project involving servlets. Using JD Java Decompiler for Eclipse I can decompile and read through all the class files making up jars in Reference libraries. Is it possible to read the contents of a WAR file in a similar way?

Also, is there a way to break down executable jar files and read the original code?

Comment: I am assuming you mean `DJ Java Decompiler`

Comment: DJ Can handle it all, not sure what your issue is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files/272595#272595

Comment: This one: http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just `unzip` the `.war` file and decompile the individual classes. [A WAR-file is a type of JAR-file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_file_format_%28Sun%29).

Comment: Thanks, I was unsure since eclipse doesn't allow to just view the contents of a war file the way it allows you to view the class files making up a jar file. Do you happen to know of any good tutorials/reference materials for working with them

Comment: For working with WAR-files? Sun `^M^M^M` Oracle should have the basic info, if you need more than that you need to be more specific. Also, google `java war` for some more information.

Comment: Here's a good start I believe: http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipio.html Also, if this answered your question, feel free to accept! :)

Comment: Yeah, I think that about covers it