# What does (filename.java.i, filename.jar.i) extension mean

Tags: filenames, java, javac

I have files named `xxx.java.i`,`xxx.java.d`,`xxx.jar.i`. I know that these file are somehow related to Java. What does this extension mean and for what is it used? Is it same type as the `.class` extension?

Comment: Of course changing a file's extension wouldn't change its contents. But what are its contents in a text editor? Do you see Java code or some garbled characters?

Comment: @Gogoo: did you find out something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at your build system for more information. It is possible that these are intermediate files that get transformed and renamed to ".java". For example, I've seen various build systems that use the ".i" suffix to mean "input", and perform various forms of variable substitution (e.g. changing something like "{VERSION_NUMBER}" to the version number of the library being compiled).

Answer (score 0):

I think they are created by someone to serve his own purpose and unless we ask the author or see the content we won't know what it the purpose is.

If you see garbled characters, it's probably java bytecode and you can use some decompiler to see the code (see: [How do I "decompile" Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)).