# Get Call-Hierarchy from Byte-Code (in Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, bytecode

I have the Java byte-code from an external library (and only the byte-code!). There is no source available. Some classes of this library have public or package-local fields. How can I find out were this fields are used? The same question for public methods.

Comment: have a look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a tool like [jd-gui](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/) to get some version of the sources, attached them to the library and then you should be able to use the call-hierarchy function on it.