# When i re-open my Java file all of the code is gone

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I am currently making a GUI in swing using the built-in Eclipse WindowBuilder. I booted up Eclipse as normal and i opened the file and there was no code at all. Only the first line has an error line which says "Syntax error, Remove these tokens". This has happened to me previously while using Netbeans and it only occurs when i use Swing. I had been working hard on this project and i would appreciate a solution to restore the code.

Comment: Have a look in explorer - are the files there? If they are, open them in notepad - is the code there?

Comment: No the code isn't there in notepad either

Comment: Tip: Add @Lissy (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: All it says is "Nul", "Nul" repeatedly.

Comment: @Lissy  There is nothing in the notepad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse deleted my java and class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879357/eclipse-deleted-my-java-and-class-files)

Comment: Right click on the file and select 'Replace With > Local History...' to see what Eclipse has in its history.

Comment: @greg-449 it says "No local history for selected resource".

Comment: Try right-clik on the file, choose Compare With/local history. This should open the History view and list previous modifications if any. If some dates are listed, double-click one one, if you liked it, you can copy modification from the source compare panel, there's little icon to do that.