# How to decompile, edit and recompile a single class file from a j2me .jar application

Tags: java-me

The .jar(mobile) application contains many class files I want to decompile  a single class fiele from it, edit it and Recompile it. Which software will help in recompiling a single class file independently?

Comment: have you checked answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to extract the files from the jar with a zip tool.

Then, as pointed by gnat, you can use a Java Decompiler as:

- Java Decompiler
- JAD

Then, you modify the .java and recompile it.

Finally you can use JAR tool to create a new jar, or even use a zip tool to replace the .class file in the original jar. Note that if the jar was signed in the first place, you have to make it from scratch and sign it.

Answer (score 0):

Most decompilers make a complete mess out of ME applications. One that gives me good results is Jadx. It's easy to use from here: http://www.javadecompilers.com/