# Byte code in java

Tags: java, bytecode

How the byte code is generated at the time of compilation. What's the Use of interpreter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `.java` file when compiled gives you a `.class` file which is in byte code.
All the code you typed (classes, methods and variables) in your `.java` file will be converted to byte code which is a **JVM** readable file and is stored with .class extension.

Answer (score 7):

`.class` file in Java contains *mostly* Java byte code + some meta information. You can use [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html) tool to examine the contents of `.class` file.

## See also

- [*Java class file* on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file)
- [How do I "decompile" Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535)

Answer (score 2):

A Java class file contains byte code and some other information.  Byte code is what your source code is compiled to, just like a C program compiles a C source file to machine code.

The Java compiler takes your English-like syntax source document and translates it into byte code. This byte code is then executed by the Java runtime environment. In this way, Java is both a compiled and interpreted language, which can be bit confusing in the beginning.