# Is there a way to convert Class object to Java source string?

Tags: java

I use `Class.forName("classname")` to get a Class object, I want to convert to Class object to String, which means decompile the java file, and show this string to GUI.

How can I do? Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to see the source code of the original class? Or just the internal string value of the class object?

Comment: @Guillaume I mean the source code of the original class, decompile the class.

Comment: @subirkumarsao thanks for reminding, I always forget to do that. :<

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java won't decompile classes for you - you need a separate decompiler for that. Try [this one](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/), which was suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/272595/626853).

Comment: thanks for your tool, I know there are many stand-alone tools for decompiling. I was wondering is there exists a jar or something I can use in my program to decompile the class?

Comment: @JerryCai: To my knowledge, the standard Java API doesn't provide anything like that; however, there may be third-party libraries for decompilation.