# Are my source codes I uploaded to Heroku open to others?

Tags: heroku

I am using Heroku to host my web server. Is my source code there available or open to others as there are some private information in my source codes? If it is, how can I prevent that? I looked at [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11115918/how-secure-is-my-application-source-code-on-heroku) questions before, but it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

Your code pushed to Heroku stays private, however it is a bad idea to store sensitive data (tokens, passwords, IDs) in the source code.

Heroku best practises is to use [Config Var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) to define secrets, these are injected into your application at runtime as environment variables (which you can access programatically - depending which language you use)