# Eclipse (files are deleted)

Tags: eclipse

This is not the first time that happens. Yesterday I code the whole day. In the end of the day I saved everything and close Eclipse. 
Today, I open Eclipse and all of my classes are gone. My folder of classes is inside of "gen (Generated Java Files" folder. Is that the problem?

I know how to restore the files..but they come with errors and I have to correct the entire classes - they are about 10. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but try with creating a folder workspace on your C: directory and save them there

Comment: Hello. Yes, I have that. The only thing good is that I make constantly backups. So I've just imported the class files and everything is Ok. But I'm not understanding why eclipse does this.

Comment: Oh hm.. im sorry but there i cant help you :( i hope someone else can .. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try following: ( This may be helpful)

Copying the `.class` files to a separate folder. (So won't loose them)

Try to find backup using time capsule or any other way.

Either able to find backup for all or fail.

After this Decompile java class files : [Decompile Java Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)