# How to import .class files into eclipse

Tags: java

I have a .jar on my desktop that my friend coded. I ahve opened the .jar in winrar to get all the .class files and things like that for it. How would i add them to a package in Eclipse.

If this is not possible is there anyway i can just open a .project file?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with the class files?

Comment: I would like to be able to edit them in eclipse

Comment: Maybe too simple: ask your friend for the source files?! (.java)

Answer (score 1):

In your place, I would just copy the .jar as is somewhere in your project and add it as a dependency by:

Right-click on project -> Project properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARs...

That way you can build new code depending on your friend's code.

I assume you are just beginning with Java or Eclipse, when you feel yourself more comfortable you may be interested in learning dependency management with automated tools as Ivy, Maven or Gradle

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html
http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/reference.html

Comment: What i am trying to do is open his .jar from my desktop into eclipse to manipulate the code. ANd yes i am just starting out

Answer (score 1):

project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries -> add external jars

I hope that will work

If you want to decompile your .class and use it as code, you can look at this question

[How do I "decompile" Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files?rq=1)

Comment: "add class path" is not an option for me?

Comment: have you try to add your jar without extracting it

Comment: I have an empty project file in Eclipse and a .jar file on my desktop, that is all.

Comment: So you have 2 options: You can import it like I said in the answer or you can convert it to code again using decompile (I mentioned link for it)

Comment: That has imported it into the referenced libraries but when i attempt to open he class file it says "the JAR file has no source attachment.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that jar is a library you want to use, import It into your project root then go to build path and select import jar to link to it

Comment: I am not very advanced yet, I don't really understand what my "Project Root" is?

Comment: This answer is a bit short to be useful. Please expand and provide more specific help.