# Implement logging in a compiled Java application?

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, decompiling

I've a standalone compiled java application. 
I don't have source files for this application and I am facing an issue. 
I need to fix this issue and need to log some information. 
I have only `.class` files at my disposal. 
Is it possible to modify these files to enable logging of some information?

Answer (score 1):

You can De-compile your class files , and can get the codes corresponding to your class files.

Then you can create new files with same name , with change in logging code .

Refer **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)** for more details about De-compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use aspectj for this.. a quick google search gave me this link.. 
http://java.jiderhamn.se/2013/08/23/debugging-third-party-libraries-with-aspectj-and-maven/

see if this helps..

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't. The only option left to you is, de-compile the class files and get the code.