# Extracting java class files from jar

Tags: java, decompiling

I had running executable jar of a Java project. Unfortunately I have lost all the source code but I still got the executable jar of it. Is there any possibility to extract my classes from the jar?

I have tried extracting but class files are in damaged shape.

Comment: what do you mean by damaged shape :)

Comment: @Abdulla - unreadable files, now I got them by using decompiler

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I "decompile" Java class files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get source from .class files , just download a decompiler from [here](http://jd.benow.ca/) and get them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked..I have got all my files back

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about decompiling or just receiving the class files? The class files can be extracted using any software capable of reading [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29). If you talk about decompiling that usually will work purly. But you could try [Jad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAD_%28JAva_Decompiler%29) which I had the best experience with.