# Get parameter list from compiled Java binary

Tags: java, c#

we have a compiled java binary i.e. file.jar and this jar takes a command as a parameter such as file1.jar command1 and in addition each command takes command parameters such as file1.jar command1 -p1=value -p2=value

we want to get a list of parameters for each command and use that in another codebase.

is there any way to get list of commands and its parameters from the compiled java binary programmatically a bit like how reflection is done in .NET?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Ummm... what? Command line arguments are passed as a `String[]` **into** the program at run-time, they aren't usually "compiled in". Unless you mean the *command line **parsing***.

Comment: OK, yes i mean command line parsing.

Comment: Decompile it and read the code.

Comment: how to decompile a java binary?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files