# How to decompile .class files using java?

Tags: java

is it possible to fully decompile a java plugin using a lightweight library or a short piece of code? What is the shortest way to do so?

Comment: Short answer No, Long answer Nooooooo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I "decompile" Java class files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible with java decompiler plugin if you use eclipse as your IDE or else there is jad.exe it converts all your .class to java. Hope this link helps you 
jd.benow.ca/