# How to convert all .class files into .java file from a .jar file

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar, .class-file

I have a .jar file and When I extract it, It gives me all the .class files present in that jar file.

I have decompiled all the .class files using http://jd.benow.ca/ tool but i want that all the .class files should save into .java files.

Right now i can see only the code but extension is not converting to .java.

Anybody Please help me in this.

Comment: If you are on a *nix machine you could write a shellscript using the `rename` utility, on windows it is probably also possible with batch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use [javadecompilers](http://www.javadecompilers.com/) and its works perfectly

[image]

and in the next step you decompile with `Upload and Decompile`and this page be showing

[image]

and thats is just `copy` the `package` folder from the `jarname.zip` and `paste` it in you project.

i tested its *work for me* .

[image]

you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files) for more.

Answer (score 2):

jd-cmd

https://github.com/kwart/jd-cmd

works fine for decompiling. I used it to convert whole jars into source code. Look up the command line options for more details, e.g. `--outputDir` for specifying a directory for the generated source code.