# Source file corrupted in NetBeans, but servlet still runs. Can i recover the code?

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

I must have shut down NetBeans incorrectly or something close to that. When I run my web application, I can call servlet `x`, and all the code runs fine, but when I open `x` in the editor, the file is blank.

I tried going through file history, no luck. Can I recover the source file? or is it gone for good?

Comment: Get the previous version from source repository. You did commit the code to a repo, right?

Comment: I shut down netbeans incorrectly tons of times and never faced the issue. If the file got corrupted I can think of two possibilities: 1. You didn't save it (weird, because the servlet wouldn't run), 2. You have a serious issue on your hard drive. If you didn't already, I'd suggest that you do a SMART scan to see if it's still healthy

Comment: You can decompile the class file, e.g. see [How do I “decompile” Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/272535/5221149)

Comment: @Andreas, thats the answer..thank you sir

Comment: @BackSlash, you're right, it could be a deeper problem...thanks for the advice