# How to edit java .class in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am very new to eclipse and I'm using it for java development.  I have no idea how I can be able to edit a class file.  Would I need a plugin to edit it?  Also I've saw on other questions about how to edit a class file and they said to decompile it then save it as a jar and more.  I have no idea how to decompile it so I'm lost.  So if anyone could help I'll appreciate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I "decompile" Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)

Comment: Are you sure you want to "edit" the .class file ? (or you want to just view it). You may already have the .java file (the actual source code).

Comment: As Subbu said, you should not normally have to decompile a .class file to do Java development. You would create or edit a .java file. What exact are you trying to do?

Comment: Im trying to edit files from Forge MDK then learn how things work and start making my own https://files.minecraftforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

Lengthy way use a Java Decompiler to view the Source code of the class file, change it and then recompile, http://jd.benow.ca/

A little complicated but an interesting way is Java Bytecode Editor I personally prefer this solution for small changes. [link](https://set.ee/jbe/).

Comment: I'll try the Java Decompiler, but I cant figure out how to install it which probably sounds wierd.  The steps on the website are confusing for me.

Comment: For eclipse integration, follow the JD-Eclipse section (http://jd.benow.ca/) blindly.

Comment: I did it but it didn't install or appear in the open with section either.  Could you tell me what to put in the name and location boxes?